# OnLoginError: codes specific to reason why there was an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I may be crazy, but I thought I remember reading that `OnLoginError` produces a value specific to what the exact error was (username/password mismatch vs. too many failed password attempts vs. account not being active, etc.). Does this exist (msdn provided me no answers) or am I just getting it confused with the error code produced when trying to add new users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you might be getting confused with this:

```
protected void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
     MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(Username.Text, Password.Text, Email.Text, passwordQuestion, SecurityAnswer.Text, true, out createStatus);
     switch (createStatus)
     {
          case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
               CreateAccountResults.Text = "The user account was successfully created!";
               break;
          case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
               CreateAccountResults.Text = "There already exists a user with this username.";
               break;

          case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
               CreateAccountResults.Text = "There already exists a user with this email address.";
               break;
          case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
               CreateAccountResults.Text = "There email address you provided in invalid.";
               break;
          case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
               CreateAccountResults.Text = "There security answer was invalid.";
               break;
          case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
               CreateAccountResults.Text = "The password you provided is invalid. It must be seven characters long and have at least one non-alphanumeric character.";

               break;
          default:
               CreateAccountResults.Text = "There was an unknown error; the user account was NOT created.";
               break;
     }
}
```

Comment: this saddens me. So i would need to create a big `if else` and check all possibilities myself then

Comment: I dont think the method you talk about gives you a reason why it failed. I guess you could override the OnAuthenticate to do custom authentication to work out why the login failed

Comment: it can be done in either spot I think, I either get the error proactively by placing it in `OnAuthenticate` or find out what the error is when one occurs by placing it in `OnLoginError` The method I was talking about be authenticating the un and pw, if that fails give an error saying so. if it passes test to see if the un is locked out, if so...